# what is the equivalent of 'x' in perldb but for python's pdb in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, pdb

I am just starting to use pdb to debug python in emacs, and I find the 'x' command missing that is available in perldb. Is there something similar in pdb?

Comment: Don't you think you should say what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the debugger commands [here](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands)

`pp` comes closest I think...